# How to calculate overall conversion percentage?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Let's a say there's an exam which has a 10% passing percentage from Prelims to Main then 15% passing percentage from Main to Interview and 2% passing percentage from interview to final selection. Then how will we calculate the overall conversion percentage for a successful candidate with their name in the final selection ?

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? It would appear that each percentage applies to the number of people not culled in the exam before. In that case, the overall percentage is just as you imagined.

$$10\%\times15\% \times2\%=0.0003=0.03\%$$